# I accidentley deleted my mp3 files on my mp3 device

Tags: sync, rhythmbox, delete, mp3-player

I accidently deleted my whole library on my mp3 player because i wanted to syncronise with rhythmbox. It deleted all my songs and put the few, that were in my folder on my device.

How can i get the songs on my device back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you did not physically overwrite your memory on your mp3-player you can try to harvest your files using **PhotoRec** from the [Testdisk Suite](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk].

Read [this guide from the makers of TestDisk/PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) for step by step procedures.

Note that folders and filenames will not be recovered by this. But you can later rename them using the mp3-tags within the files.